# Titanium CLI command 'info' get stuck

Tags: titanium

I'm having some trouble with the whole Titanium environment, so in order to find what's wrong, I wanted to use this command:

```
ti info
```

But it get stuck on the loading animation for hours..Not even an error..
I though it could come from some Titanium CLI dependencies or something like that, but the command `ti setup check` tells me that the titanium CLI and is dependancies are installed, up-do-date, etc..

Does anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: What's your titanium version?

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.0 for the CLI. Same version for the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to get this command to work fine again, but I went through dozens of thing so I can't be sure that last one was what did the trick..

I ran the command `ti setup` in order to do the quick setup and reset all the values and set the Titanium SDK back on 3.2.3 version instead of the 3.3.0.

EDIT:
Aaaaaaand...it's gone, nevermind, it's coming back and forth...Quite an unstable environment...